# Accessing Kedro CLI from an existing project

Tags: installation, kedro

I have an existing project, cloned with `git clone`.

After I `pip install kedro` I can run `kedro info` fine but I dont seem to have access to the projects CLI for example if I try to run`kedro install` I get the following error:

```
Usage: kedro [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'kedro -h' for help.

Error: No such command 'install'.
```

Any clues on what to do for existing projects are much appreciated.

Not sure if this matters but I am working inside a conda environment which is inside a docker container.

Comment: for kedro  CLI to work, you must be in the top level folder of a kedro project, check for the presence of  .kedro.yml and kedro_cli.py files.

Comment: Yep I am doing this at the top level of the project. The kedro_cli.py file is available there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project CLIs are available if you run `kedro` at your Kedro project directory.

1. Run `kedro new` to create a Kedro project
2. `cd <your-kedro-project>`
3. `kedro` at the project directory

And you should see the project level CLIs

[image]

Also for your existing project, check if you have `kedro_cli.py` at your project directory.

Comment: I  doing this already. See comment above. Thanks for answering though, any other suggestions?

Comment: I can't accept the answer because its for new project created with `kedro new`, I need information on projects cloned with `git clone`.

Comment: ok my mistake, I was not copying the kedro_cli.py file into the container. Apologies. Accepted your answer now.